# Can I use just bootstrap 4 (not react-bootsrap) insinde my React app?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Or is bad idea? I read something about jQuery and react don't work together is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do, in theory. In your React render you can use normal HTML tags (ish.. JSX style) and specify bootstrap4 classes on them via className attribute instead of class. If you're just using the grid and the css helpers for position, text-align, typography then you won't come up against any big issues except more scaffolding work.  But if you're using the components then you're at a big disadvantage as you'll have to manage state yourself and thus repeating work, as a trivial example the pagination control you'll have write the conditional expressions to append 'active' on className  yourself, rather than just using PaginationItem and letting the component manage the active boolean, but things get much more complicated with other components. In addition you'll lose a lot of development assistance that propType validation provides.

I'd suggest you pull back and work through the https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html documentation first before thinking about bootstrap, jQuery etc.. and you'll be a much better position to make a call on this. If you hit react copying and pasting and not knowing the basics you won't get far and you'll end up with a holy mess even if you do get it working. You generally don't need jQuery with react, the only time we see it is when you are using a jQuery component and then wire up/down event handlers to component state by the React lifecycle methods (where an open source react component hasn't already done so).

tl;dr - make sure you understand how react works (probably most importantly state) and the question will answer itself.